# Log4j appender append/store log file to a particular location in Storm cluster environment

Tags: java, log4j2, apache-storm

Is there any way to change the location of the log file for one particular appender of log4j in a Storm cluster environment?
Suppose I want to keep all logger files of `RollingFileInfoappender` at `/logs/storm` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. You can add a `log4j2.xml` file to your `resources`-folder and specify the appenders as you like.

For instance:

```xml
        <RollingFile name="mylog"
                 fileName="path/to/log.file"
                 filePattern="path/to/log.file.%i.gz"
                 append="false"
                 createOnDemand="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>${patternNoTime}</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4"/>
        </RollingFile>
```